# excluded field in model form still required

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'name': 'radioInline'}), choices=POST_CHOICES)


    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','desc','image','url',)
```

I have the following model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Post(models.Model):  
    entity = models.ForeignKey('companies.Entity')
    title = models.CharField('Post Title', max_length=128, unique=True) 
    desc = models.TextField('Description', blank=True, null=True)
    post_type = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_CHOICES)
    image = models.ImageField('Post Image', upload_to='post', blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

When I submit the form, I get the error:

post_type field error: This field is required.

I want to populate this field after form.is_valid method.

Since this field is not in the required fields tuple, shouldn't it not be required?

I have also tried adding:

```
post_type = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

Though I get the same error.

Is there something else going on?

Comment: There is a different between field required in the form and field required in the model, if you want that post_type be null then add null=True, otherwise you can populate it before the call to is_valid, which will not affect what appends after because you don't care about this field apparently right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'name': 'radioInline'}), choices=POST_CHOICES, required=False)
```

add `required=False` will fine

---

your `post_type = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_CHOICES, blank=True)` in models.py not work because you have override post_type field in ModelForm and not set it to `required=False`

---

if you want `post_type = models.IntegerField(choices=POST_CHOICES, blank=True)` work just:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','desc','image','url', 'post_type')
```